# Target [League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer]

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I've recently set up a new `Laravel 5.5` project on `Ubuntu 16.04` with an `NGINX` server. I've followed all the correct steps and double checked everything more than once. I've installed `Laravel/Passport` and double checked those set up instructions as well.

I'm building an `API` that requires a login for most endpoints, which is done via `password_grant` with `laravel/passport` but can also consumes a `Facebook` auth token - instead of writing my own Facebook Auth Token verify, I've chosen to use a larval plugin. [`composer require danjdewhurst/laravel-passport-facebook-login`](https://github.com/danjdewhurst/Laravel-Passport-Facebook-Login) However, this plugin doesn't seem to install easily for me.

I am receiving an error on any `composer` install or update command I issue:

> Target [League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\ClientRepositoryInterface] is not instantiable while building [League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer].

I have played around with the `config/app.php` file as well as the `uses` for all of the files and providers that were installed with the plugin. I have gone through every post here to try and fix the issue as well.

If anyone has any insight or a fix for this issue I'd appreciate it. Any help would help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this to be an issue with the order of Laravel's auto discovery of packages. Obviously the Facebook Grant package needs to load after `laravel/passport` but this was not happening.

My solution was to add the following to my `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/passport",
            "danjdewhurst/laravel-passport-facebook-login"
        ]
    }
}
```

and then the following to my `config/app.php` in the providers array:

```
\Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
\Danjdewhurst\PassportFacebookLogin\FacebookLoginGrantProvider::class,
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you

Comment: Thanks, adding `\Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class` to the `Providers` array in `app.php` worked.

Answer (score 1):

After adding `Laravel\PassportServiceProvider::class` to `config/app.php` providers. I just deleted the **.php** from `bootstrap/cache/` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to composer update and encounter the same problem.

Then I notice the dependencies in https://github.com/danjdewhurst/Laravel-Passport-Facebook-Login stated

```
"laravel/passport": "^4.0",
```

I solved my problem after updating my passport

Comment: I was already running `"laravel/passport": "^4.0",` - so sadly this did not fix my issue.